# Change color by state of attribute. HTML, Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need help.

I am developing a web application to register lost objects.

Missing objects are displayed on a table. Objects have an attribute equal to 0 for not delivered.
When it is delivered it goes to the value of the attribute equal to 1.

I would like to highlight the lines of objects already delivered (with the attribute equal to 1) for example with the green background color.

[image: lost objects]

My table:

```
  <tr>

            <th scope="col">Description of objects </th>
            <th scope="col">local</th>
            <th scope="col"> who find ?</th>
            <th scope="col">With value of without value</th>
            <th scope="col">Destination actualy</th>
            <th scope="col">When it has found</th>
            <th scope="col">When is has delivery</th>
            <th scope="col"> State of objects</th>

            <th scope="col"> Ações </th>
          </tr>
```

Now part with PHP 7 with Mysql

```
$rs = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM Perdidos");
$rs_users = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM users");
$registro_users = $rs_users->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

if($rs->execute() and $rs_users->execute())
{

```
while($registro = $rs->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) 
{



    echo "<td>" . $registro->description_Perdidos. "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $registro->local_Perdidos. "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $registro->whoFind_Perdidos. "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $registro->withValueOrWithOutValue_Perdidos. </td>";
    echo "<TD>" . $registro->destinationActualy_Perdidos . "</TD>";
    echo "<TD>" . $registro->WhenIsHasFound_Perdidos. "</TD>";
    echo "<TD>" . $registro->WhenIsHasDelivery_Perdidos . "</TD>";
    echo "<TD>" . $registro->stateOfObjects         . "</TD>";
    echo "<TD>";
    echo "</TD>";
```

echo "";

Comment: Need to see your html

Answer (score 1):

Add data-attr property at each row level which is mapped with your object attribute(0 or 1) and you can apply the style using below example:

```
$('#tableId').find('tr[data-attr="1"]').css("background-color", "green")
```

Comment: Sorry but I did not understand. I will do this shortly.

I'll post part of my code.

Thanks for the patience and attention.

Answer (score 0):

First thing - I think you are missing a `<tr>` tag around your `<td>` elements inside your while loop.

Inside your while loop you could check if the item is delivered. If so - put `class='delivered'` on the `<tr>`

Then using CSS you can style the rows which have the class 'delivered' like this:

```
.delivered { 
  background: #eee
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Tks tks tks! Simple and perfect